# How to fix the "Unit docker.service could not be found." error?

Tags: sudo, snap, services, docker, administration

How do I simply pull and run `hello-world`?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ snap list docker
Name    Version   Rev   Tracking       Publisher   Notes
docker  20.10.14  1779  latest/stable  canonical✓  -
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo systemctl start docker
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo systemctl status docker
Unit docker.service could not be found.
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker

[Unit docker.service could not be found](https://askubuntu.com/q/977961/847449)

Comment: What does `systemctl docker status` show?

Comment: service not found @WMRamadan

Comment: I would recommend installing docker with `apt` and not as a `snap`. The `snap` version has somewhat limited functionality compared to the `apt` version.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, to remedy the "Unit docker.service could not be found" issue, I needed to run...

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

(Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)

Comment: I'm not sure what that does, but it worked!

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the snap version of docker is just the docker client, and not the actual docker daemon and service. I recommend going to their site and trying to install it using their instructions as it'll likely have the full package

Instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) for Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

For my case, after install Docker Desktop from .deb file, I ran

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

after that, I tried to run the service

```
systemctl start docker
```

and it works!
Peviously after I ran `sudo apt --fix-broken install` when failed to install docker .deb file, it didn't mention the docker-ce is needed. And found out that docker-ce is needed later.